# Angular JS - repeat image tag for numbers in array

Tags: jquery, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm modifying my question a bit since I was not able to get a proper solution previously.

I have an array products_page=["7","8","6","9","5","7","8","9","8","7"]

Each time the below table's  is ng-repeated based on json values, the image tag (Commented as: Please note this image tag needs to be repeated) needs to be repeated 7 times on first ng-repeat, 8 times on second ng-repeat, 6 times on third ng-repeat and so on....

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="user in users[0].tvseries | filter: searchText | filter: genre.config | orderBy:predicate">
            <td>
                <img ng-src="{{user.thumbnail}}" alt="" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>{{user.tv_show_name}}</div>
                <div>{{user.brief_description}}</div>
                <div>Rating:
                <!--Please note this image tag needs to be repeated-->
                <img ng-repeat="rate in getNumber(products_page[$index]) track by $index" src="img/star.png" width="15" height="15" />
                <!--Please note this image tag needs to be repeated-->
                {{user.rating}}</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>SHOW TIME:{{user.show_time}}</div>
                <div>GENRE:{{user.genre}}</div>
                <div>SEASON:{{user.current_season}}</div>
                <div>EPISODE:{{user.current_episode}}</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: It is working.. http://jsfiddle.net/cHQLH/89/ just change `myNumber` with a real number :)

Comment: Hi Lorenzo, I want that number to be coming from my json. The variable ($scope.products_page) mentioned above has the array of ratings from my json. But seems my image tag is not getting repeated.

Comment: Then what is the `num` parameter in `getNumber` function.. It is never used..

Comment: Hi Lorenzo, sorry that was my mistake. It should have been getNumber(user.rating) where I said, {{user.rating}} has the exact number of times the image tag needs to be repeated. I have also modified the controller to return an array of {{user.rating}}. But still I dont get the image repeated :( And the fiddle I have posted, is just a reference I got while browsing for a solution.

Comment: If `{{user.rating}}` has the number of items then just do `ng-repeat="rate in user.rating"`

Comment: I have modified my html to -> <img ng-repeat="rate in user.rating" src="img/star.png" width="15" height="15" /> Still I could see only one image. Its not repeating. :(

Comment: if you do alert($user.rating) in your controller what is the result ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50598/discussion-between-flashyfuddyfuddy-and-lorenzo)

Answer (score 0):

If I have got your question, you may use $index of parent in the child ng-repeat.

In your html:

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="i in getNumber(myNumber)">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="j in getNumber($index+1)"> <span>{{$index+1}}</span>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cHQLH/90/

Comment: Hi Abraham, I'm not trying for a nested ng-repeat. I just want to repeat an image tag for n number of times. That "n" is noting but {{user.rating}}

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, your're trying to repeat the star-image a certain number of times to display a rating, like 7 out of 10 stars.

If that's the case:
`ng-repeat`only works for arrays, that means you cannot directly iterate over the number "7" to repeat the image 7 times (7 just being an example of one of your entries in products_page).

You have to convert each individual entry into an array with the correct length, one way to do that would be to use a filter:

```
app.filter('range', function () {
  return function range (count) {
    var i = 0,
      temp = [];
    count = Number(count) || 0;
    for (i; i<count; i++) {
      temp.push(i);
    }
    return temp;
  };
});
```

and use it like this in your markup `<img ng-repeat="rate in (products_page[$index] | range)" src="img/star.png" width="15" height="15" />`.

Even better - abstract this logic into a reusable directive (in addition to the filter - or add the filter logic into the directive's link function - whatever suits you best):

```
app.directive('rating', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {
      value : '='
    },
    template: '<img src="img/star.png" width="15" height="15" ng-repeat="rate in (value | range)" />'
  };
});
```

And use it like so `<rating value="products_page[$index]"></rating>`.

See here for a working, trimmed down, example: http://plnkr.co/edit/Uat2Gonz3Wlg2Mgj1O22?p=preview